# python replace string at 2 parts in one line

Tags: python, regex

Source string: " **LTRIM(RTRIM(AB.ITEM_ID)) AS ITEM_NUMBER,** "

convert LTRIM RTRIM to just TRIM and remove extra right parentheses.
I need this to be converted to " **TRIM(AB.ITEM_ID) AS ITEM_NUMBER,** "

Have many sql files which are written long back and need to be corrected as part of platform migration.
this source string could be tons of places in each sql.
I tried doing **line.replace('LTRIM(RTRIM', 'TRIM')** works but leaves with the extra right bracket.
I want the extra brackget also to be removed at oneshot
sample inputs:

1.REPLACE(**LTRIM(RTRIM**(NVL(AB.ITEM_SHORT_DESC,AB.ITEM_DESC))**)**,',','') AS SHORT_DESC

2.**LTRIM(RTRIM(AB.ITEM_ID)**)** AS ITEM_NUMBER,**

please be advised the input is a full file as string and can have multiple occurrences and not just one line with this LTRIM(RTRIM . Sure have to use some regex etc.

I am using python 3.8.2

Comment: Python does not have an AS opperator in this context? What is the AS trying to accomplish?

Comment: is this VBA code? or excel formulas?

Comment: The only problem is you don't know where the right parenthesis really is.

Comment: And you would have to use the new `import regex` module to use recursion to find and identify where the right parenthesis is. Even using recursion would only allow you to do the _outter_ LTRIM(RTRIM stuff If you wanted to do the inner stuff, you'd have to _re-run_ the regex on the string until there is no LTRIM(RTRIM's left I can give you the recursive regex if you wifll use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Python replacement regex engine to do recursion and
the replacement you want.

Regex `r"LTRIM\(RTRIM(\((?:(?>(?!LTRIM\(RTRIM\(|[()])[\S\s])+|\(|(?R))*\))\)"`
Replace with `r"TRIM\1"`

Sample

```
import regex

src = '''
.. LTRIM(RTRIM(AB.ITEM_ID)) AS ITEM_NUMBER,
 .. REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(NVL(AB.ITEM_SHORT_DESC,AB.ITEM_DESC))),',','') AS SHORT_DESC
.. LTRIM(RTRIM(AB.ITEM_ID))** AS ITEM_NUMBER,**
'''

srcnew = regex.sub(r"LTRIM\(RTRIM(\((?:(?>(?!LTRIM\(RTRIM\(|[()])[\S\s])+|\(|(?R))*\))\)", r"TRIM\1", src)

print( srcnew )
```

see https://repl.it/repls/DelightfulSatisfiedCore#main.py

Comment: Thanks a lot , had issues but after installing regex it worked $python -m pip install regex